# Strange scroll-correction on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have made a page that starts with a full (100% by 100%) image div.
This div will always fill up the page before scrolling.

Then I have another div with an image.

On desktop there is no problem.

However, on mobile when this page is loaded and I swipe my finger  to give it a little scroll, then when the phone finished scrolling, it snaps / auto scrolls back a bit. It also appears to zoom-in a little.

I think it's due to the 100% on HTML and BODY tag, because if I remove that, then there is no scrolling correction.

I have tried this on several Android phones and always the same. How do I fix this? Here's the code.

```
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.first {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/VWYl1EC.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

div.second {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/PbV1Grl.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>

<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is when the first div on a page has a height in %, this auto correction scroll will happen on Android phones.

The solution is to set the height in PX instead by using jQuery.
For example:

```
$('.firstdiv').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

use your css like following:-

```
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.first {
  max-width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/VWYl1EC.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height:300px; /* as you needed */
}

div.second {
  max-width:100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/PbV1Grl.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height:300px; /* as you needed */
}
```

Comment: No, this won't make the first image full screen before the scrolling starts

Comment: Yes, the problem is if the first div contains a % in height (instead of pixel) then the auto scrolling appears... Maybe i need to use javascript to lookup the window height and set it in pixelx upon load.